# CSS and javascript text and image positioning

Tags: html, css, ios, image, position

I have a large text. I've made 3 columns with the following CSS:

```
.columns {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
text-align: justify;
}
```

It has to work in Safari. This works just fine. But now I would like to place an image to the top of the second column.
How can I have this result?

---

Edit: This was my start of doing the thing, but I would like to say that the important thing is to have the result in any way, so I can drop this css in case it can be solved without this.

---

Edit 2: I've solved it with the jquery colonizer plugin. I had to add 3-5 lines of code to the plugin. I need this for the iPad, where I have arrange the text and image like I mentioned before. I think this is the simplest method to have this job done.

In case you need the solution, feel free to e-mail me.

@flynfish, please post it as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: I am assuming the requirement is to dynamically create the columns? So you can't just float 3 divs beside each other to simulate multiple columns?

Comment: I can do it, but the text is dynamic and I can't determine the size of it. It has to be done from code. Do you think is it possible?

Comment: You could try using this [jquery columnizer plugin](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) and then add your image into the second column. This could work because the plugin splits the text into divs.

Comment: It is possible that it will work. Thank you, I am going to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this is possible. The browser determines where to break the content and there's no way via CSS to insert something at those points. The closest thing I've been able to come up with uses the column-break-before: property (-webkit-column-break-before, -moz-column-break-before, column-break-before).

For example:

**CSS**:

```
div#multicolumnElement {
    -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;
    column-count: 4;
}
.special {
    -webkit-column-break-before:always;
    -moz-column-break-before:always;
    column-break-before:always;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="multicolumnElement">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur mattis, lectus 
nec tempor auctor, urna urna venenatis nisi, ac pellentesque est felis egestas lorem! 
Duis lectus dui, commodo in varius sed, bibendum at eros. Donec ultricies, est quis 
pretium porttitor, neque arcu auctor dui, sit amet adipiscing erat est id massa. 
Morbi at elementum <img class="special" src="http://dummyimage.com/200x150/000/fff" />lectus. Donec fermentum massa sit amet nisi tempus sed vestibulum 
tortor pellentesque. Aliquam dictum, sapien a luctus ultricies, ipsum erat dignissim 
tellus, in ultricies mi lorem tempor velit. Vivamus ornare nulla sed arcu elementum 
pharetra. </p>
<p>Phasellus cursus felis sed felis porta tempor. Vestibulum at eleifend ligula. 
Vestibulum hendrerit ligula at elit lacinia at ultricies metus fringilla! Vestibulum 
ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Morbi 
ultrices tortor vel ipsum imperdiet imperdiet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi 
eu leo quis lectus aliquet elementum. Aenean porta interdum nibh id posuere? Phasellus 
nisl lorem, semper bibendum semper at, malesuada non odio. </p>
<p>In ullamcorper eros quis nisi pharetra tincidunt. Vestibulum ac elit nunc, sed 
laoreet leo! Duis et nulla sit amet lorem gravida lacinia. Cras massa ipsum, semper 
in mattis ut, fringilla in nisi. Nulla mauris urna, feugiat sed convallis id, facilisis 
et sem. Donec egestas ultricies commodo. Aliquam eget nulla enim, et dictum nisi. 
In faucibus, leo vitae congue convallis, elit eros venenatis leo, nec lobortis sapien 
orci at nunc. </p>
</div>
```

This produces four columns of text with an image at the top of the second column, however depending on the amount of text and the space available, it's possible that this may not always turn out as you want.

I'd have linked to a jsFiddle example but it seems to be down ATM.

Comment: I agree. According to the spec: "It is not possible to set properties/values on column boxes. For example, the background of a certain column box cannot be set and a column box has no concept of padding, margin or borders."

Comment: please link the jsFiddle if it is up